# .Net Core 3.1 OpenIdConnect with AWS Cognito

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I've been trying to get AWS Incognito working with ASP.NET Core 3.1 all day and am missing sime essential piece.

The code below is close because:

**It Will**

- Let the user go through the built-in ASP.NET Identity user registration and login pages
- That will result in records for the user in both the `AspNetUsers` table and the `AspNetUserLogins` table.
- Appear to log the user in when they pass through the ASP.Net Identity UI `ExternalLogin.cshml` page's Callback method: [image]
- But in reality ASP.Net Identity is unaware of this user
  [image]
- In addition it will result in an infinite loop if you try to access an authorized page, bouncing between the requested page, the AWS Cognito server, and the "signin-oidc" built-in route.

[image]

The line I suspect the most is:

`options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;`

As the code comments mention, commentng out this line will break the built-in registration, but solve the infiniteloop problem (as well as let the openid claims cookie stay populated).

It's pretty clear that it's *close*, but there's something not quite linked up to bring it all together.

```
var awsCognitoRegion = "us-east-1";
var awsCognitoPoolId = "******";
var metaDataAddress = $"https://cognito-idp.{awsCognitoRegion}.amazonaws.com/{awsCognitoPoolId}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
//var awsCognitoResponseType = "code";
var awsCognitoMetaAddress = metaDataAddress;
var awsCognitoClientId = "*******************";
var awsCognitoSecret = "**********************";

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    //fixes "Error loading external login information" error on Identity Login page / callback
    //after external login...but breaks identity/cookie/claims?
    //
    //Also Causes infinite redirect problem via signin-oidc
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

    //show all claims since MS filters some out...
    options.ClaimActions.Clear();

    //Tell .Net Core identity where to find the "name"
    //options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";

    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.MetadataAddress = metaDataAddress;
    options.ClientId = awsCognitoClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = awsCognitoSecret;

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    //I think all I need here is email
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    //options.Scope.Add("aws.cognito.signin.user.admin");
});
```

Comment: Haha yes, thank you.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

As these authentication things always are, it ended up being one property missing/set wrong.

In this case it was that the SigninManager was checking if the Identity had `principal.Identities.Any(i => i.AuthenticationType == IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);` (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs).  This is why even though the Identity would have `IsAuthentictated = true`, the built-in ASP.Net Identity pages were broken, because that value was set to `AuthenticationTypes.Federation`.

After more digging around I discovered that in the options of the `.AddOpenIdConnect` method there is a way to set that:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters.AuthenticationType = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
```

That finally made ASP.Net Identity aware that I was logged in (through OpenId).

Comment: Hi @FirstDivision can you please share the code or point at the working tutorial. I'm trying to implement the same OpenID connect flow to Cognito. Specifically, signin/signout functionality.